# Location.newInstance method gives error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void newInstance(Decimal, Decimal) from the type String

Tags: apex

When I run a code snippet in console, it doesnt give any error but when I use it inside an apex method, I keep getting this error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void newInstance(Decimal, Decimal) from the type String. Both the lines in first code have same error. geoLatitude and geoLatitude are defined initilly.

Relevant Code:

```
 for(AccountContactRelation ac : accConMap){

                Location locAcc = Location.newInstance(ac.Account.BillingLatitude, ac.Account.BillingLongitude);
                Location locZip = Location.newInstance(geoLatitude, geoLongitude);
                acConDistanceMap.put(ac.Id, Location.getDistance(locZip, locAcc, 'mi') );

            }
```

But when i put similar code in console, it works and gives me location.

```
 AccountContactRelation acc = [SELECT Id, Account.BillingLatitude, Account.BillingLongitude FROM AccountContactRelation Where AccountId = '001f000001POxdiAAD' LIMIT 1];
Location locAcc = Location.newInstance(acc.Account.BillingLatitude, acc.Account.BillingLongitude);
System.debug(locAcc);
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a line of code in your class that looks like this:

```
String location;
```

This overrides the class, because it is in a local scope.

Rename this variable, *or* use the System class to let the compiler know you mean the class Location, not the variable:

```
System.Location locAcc = System.Location.newInstance(ac.Account.BillingLatitude, ac.Account.BillingLongitude);
System.Location locZip = System.Location.newInstance(geoLatitude, geoLongitude);
```

This effect is known as "shadowing", and can happen any time you use a variable name or local class the same as a system class. It is best to avoid this problem by not using such names. See [Namespace, Class, and Variable Precedence](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_namespace_precedence.htm) for more information.

The "hint" used to solve this puzzle is in the error:

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void newInstance(Decimal, Decimal) from the type String

This tells me that you've declared a variable named `location` with the data type of `String`, and you're trying to call a method that doesn't exist on that object.

Comment: I cant believe that was it :) I used System.Location as well but forgot to use it after the equal to. Thank you @sfdcfox !!

Comment: I have an additional question: I might post it separately. Is it possible to use DISTANCE in SOQL for lookup field something like this? [SELECT Id, AccountId, ContactId, Account.BillingAddress,  DISTANCE(Account.BillingAddress, GEOLOCATION(:geoLatitude, :geoLongitude), 'mi') dist                                                                    FROM AccountContactRelation WHERE                                              DISTANCE(Account.BillingAddress, GEOLOCATION(:geoLatitude, :geoLongitude), 'mi') <:miles ]

Comment: @P.Shri I'm not sure... never tried.

Comment: It doesnt work: Gives me internal salesforce error.